# Cron job -many duplicate posts

Tags: php

i have news aggregator website and have many sources need sometime to update in one minute maybe 7 new posts i make more cron jobs in cpanel every minute,every two minutes,5minutes but problem is duplicate posts how to resolve this can anyone help me with some shell script?
thanks in advance!

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: i have cron job in cpanel wget -O /dev/null https://look.mk/?wp_automatic=job but fetch one post when i have more crons i have duplicate posts i need some shell script i had before but i lost

Comment: Unless you share the code that runs on the cron job, we can't really help.

Comment: i have wp automatic plugin from codecanyon dont have code for cron

Comment: Sounds like you will need to contact Codecanyon / the developer.

Comment: they can't help me with script :(